# SQL Server; STDistance function not working in update statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial, sqlgeography

I have a table like this

**EventTable** (IsFar *bit*, Location *geography*)

**No Problem with Select statement:**
I can simply run this with no error:

```
DECLARE @center AS  GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(50, -160, 4326);        
SELECT * FROM EventTable WHERE  @center.STDistance(Location) > 100000
```

**Not working with Update statement:** but when I want to update the `IsFar` column based on its distance from a certain point, it throw exception

> Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @center AS  GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(50, -160, 4326);        
UPDATE EventTable SET IsFar = @center.STDistance(Location) > 100000
```

Anyone can explain why this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `Where` clause

```
UPDATE EventTable SET IsFar = @center.STDistance(Location) 
where @center.STDistance(Location) > 100000
```

Based on your comment

```
UPDATE eventtable 
SET    isfar = CASE 
                 WHEN @center.STDistance(location) > 100000 THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END
```

If you are using `Sql Server 2012+` then you can use `IIF`

```
UPDATE eventtable 
SET    isfar = IIF(@center.STDistance(location) > 100000, 1, 0)
```

Replace `0` and `1` in `case` statement based on your requirement

Comment: Good idea but `IsFar` is of type `bit` not `float`

Comment: Yes, it solves the problem but I didn't expect this much code and I'm surprised why SQL just didn't  support that syntax

Comment: simply its not a valid syntax. Both functionally and technically your query has mistakes. You are trying to assign `@center.STDistance(Location)` to `BIT` column and to check a condition and update you need to use `CASE` or `IIF` statement

Comment: But I was trying to assign `@center.STDistance(Location) > 100000` to bit

Comment: What about this: `select @center.STDistance(location) > 100000 from EventTable`. this also throw the same exception.

Comment: Because it is not correct. Whats your expectation when you write `select @center.STDistance(location) > 100000 from EventTable`. What you want to to display in query result

Comment: Maybe I'm looking at the SQL with C# glasses, but I expect to return some 0 or 1 values as the result.

Comment: In `SQL` you need `case` statement to **validate** the condition and return `0` or `1` based on result